# Why doesnt my block render in the header?

Tags: static-block, blocks

This is my Local.XML

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="cms/block" name="topsocial" as="topsocial">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>topsocial</block_id>
        </action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

This is my header.phtml placement

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topsocial') ?>
```

I created the static block in the admin panel with the same name. May I ask why its not working? The block is 4 LI's with Font Awesome icons.

Comment: change alias name and name of block

Comment: where have you added that code?

Comment: Its in my header.phtml.  Change alias and name?  Do they conflict?

Comment: no..just change 
 
change alias name and name of block  for any reason same block name is used in other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The error was in my xml.  I forgot to wrap my reference tags inside of default tags.